# Utilizar un programa abierto con una tubería

Tags: c

Estoy creando un pipe al programa "gnuplot" utilizando un script con este código:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() 
 {
   FILE *pipe;

   if(fork() == 0)
     pipe = popen("gnuplot\n","w"):

   wait(); //Con esto evito que el programa se cierre

   return 0;
 }
```

"gnuplot" se abre bien, en la misma shell donde ejecuto el script, pero después no me deja utilizar el propio gnuplot. Me imagino que esto será por que al escribir en el shell, de hecho estoy pasando comandos al script y no al gnuplot. ¿Hay alguna forma sencilla de hacer que los comandos que escribo en la terminal vayan directamente al pipe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algunas cosas sobre `popen()`:

- Internamente `popen()` llama a `fork()` para lanzar el comando en un subproceso. No necesitas por tanto hacer tú el `fork()` (a menos que sea para otra cosa).
- Cuando llamas a `popen()` especificando como segundo parámetro `"w"`, significa que pretendes *escribir* en el tubo desde el programa que lanzó el subproceso. La salida estándar del comando lanzado irá a la misma salida estándar que tenía el proceso que lo lanzó. Si quieres mandarle cosas al subprograma desde el proceso que lo lanzó, escribe en el tubo (usando `fputs()`, `fprintf()` o lo que sea)
- Si hubieras llamado a `popen()` especificando como segundo parámetro `"r"`, entonces significaría que tu proceso querrá *leer* del tubo. En ese caso la salida estándar del comando no irá a la pantalla, sino al tubo. En cambio su entrada estándar no vendrá del tubo, sino de la misma entrada estándar del proceso que lo lanzó.

Así pues, parece que tienes dos formas de conectar la entrada estándar de tu proceso con la del comando lanzado:

1. Usa `popen()` en modo `"r"`. De este modo la entrada estándar de tu proceso será la entrada estándar del comando lanzado, sin necesidad de hacer nada. Ahora bien, no verás la salida del comando (a menos que te ocupes de leerla) ya que esa irá al tubo.
2. Usando `popen()` en modo `"w"` como tú lo tenías, el proceso que lanza el subcomando debe ocuparse por sí mismo de ir copiando lo que encuentre en su entrada estándar al tubo, mediante un bucle que finalizará cuando no haya más entrada estándar.

Veamos un par de ejemplos, uno de cada caso. En este caso, en vez de `gnuplot` voy a lanzar el comando `"awk '{print(toupper($0))}'"`, que se ocupa de ir leyendo su entrada estándar, pasándola a mayúscula y volcándola en la salida estándar.

## Usando popen en modo "r"

En este modo, la entrada estándar del proceso principal será conectada automáticamente con la del subproceso, sin hacer nada especial:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    FILE *pipe;

    printf("Lanzando comando\n");
    pipe = popen("awk '{print(toupper($0))}' > salida\n", "r");
    printf("Esperando a que el comando termine\n");
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Terminando main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Si compilas y ejecutas este programa, se quedará esperando a que escribas algo. Si pones un par de líneas como "hola" y "adios", ese texto estará siendo recibido por el subcomando, que es `awk`, el cual lo pasará a mayúsculas y lo volcará a su salida estándar. Por desgracia, la salida estándar no es visible (es el tubo). No obstante, quizás en tu caso con `gnuplot` sí que puedas ver los efectos sobre la ventana gráfica que se haya abierto.

## Usando popen en modo "w"

En este modo es la salida estándar del subcomando la que será igual a la salida estándar del proceso que lo lanzó. Ahora sí podremos ver la salida de `awk`, pero en cambio la entrada estándar de `awk` estará conectada al tubo, por lo que para enviarle cosas necesitamos escribir en el tubo. Así:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TAM_BUFF 100

int main(){
    FILE *pipe;
    char buff[TAM_BUFF];

    printf("Lanzando comando\n");
    pipe = popen("awk '{print(toupper($0))}'\n", "w");
    printf("Comando lanzado. Copiando entrada estándar a tubo\n");
    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        fgets(buff, TAM_BUFF, stdin);
        fputs(buff, pipe);
        fflush(pipe);
    }
    printf("Detectado EOF. Esperando que termine subproceso\n");
    pclose(pipe);
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Terminado main\n");
    return 0;

}
```

## Sin usar popen

Finalmente, si quieres conectar *ambas* la entrada y la salida estándar de tu proceso con las del subcomando, entonces `popen` no es la mejor opción, pues no te da esa posibilidad. Puede construirte tú tu propio "popen" haciendo uso de `fork()` y `execlp()`:

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    printf("Lanzando comando\n");
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execlp("awk", "awk", "{print(toupper($0))}", NULL);
    }
    printf("Esperando a que termine el subcomando\n");
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Terminando main\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Quizás era esto lo que intentabas originalmente.

Comment: execlp se parece más a lo que buscaba , gracias. Sin embargo ahora tengo un problema: ¿cómo puedo enviar algo desde main al subproceso (es decir, el equivalente de "escribir en el tubo" desde main)?

Comment: @Guillermo.D.S. No entiendo.. el comando `gnuplot` está leyendo de su entrada estándar. ¿Quieres que, a la vez que esa entrada estándar es la mismoa que la del proceso que la creó, poder escribir en ella? O sea, una vez lanzado el programa lo que el usuario teclea en la terminal va a `gnuplot`, pero a la vez el el programa que sigue en ejecución (el padre) puede también enviar comandos? ¿es eso? ¿Y cómo evitas que los comandos "se mezclen"? No le encuentro mucho sentido... Igual vale más que preguntes qué quieres hacer y no cómo se hace.

Comment: (me doy cuenta de que no he sido muy claro). Sí, es exactamente eso. La razón de ser es que quiero crear un script de configuración (escala de los ejes, colores, título, y cosas así), de tal forma que yo lance un programa "config.out", se abra la interfaz de gnuplot, se envíen desde main() los comandos de configuración, y luego me deje a mí usar gnuplot desde su interfaz

Comment: @Guillermo.D.S. ¿Y no será mejor usar [esto](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-6900018)? (Un archivo `.gnuplot` en la carpeta, que es leido y ejecutado cada vez que gnuplot arranca)

Comment: @Guillermo.D.S. Si por lo que sea necesitas hacerlo desde un programa, entonces podrías adaptar el segundo ejemplo con `popen()`, para que primero abra el archivo, lea las líneas y las escriba en la tubería, y después continúe leyendo de `stdin` y volcando en la tubería.

Comment: Sí, una modificación de tu segundo ejemplo creo que funcionará. Puedo volcar sobre gnuplot los datos que previamente lea de stdin con el programa principal (interactuando con gnuplot a través de main ). La razón de no usar .gnuplot es para hacerlo más general y poder utilizarlo en otros programas, simplemente. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasar comandos a gnuplot con la opción:

```
-e "comandos" (EJ: gnuplot -e "help", verás la ayuda)
```

Para pasarlos desde el main tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* command = "gnuplot";
    FILE* pipe;

    if(fork() == 0) {
        for(int cmd = 1; cmd < argc; cmd++) {
            command = (char*) realloc(command, sizeof(char) * (strlen(command) + strlen(argv[cmd])));
            strcat(command, " ");
            strcat(command, argv[cmd]);
        }
        strcat(command, "\n");
        pipe = popen(command, "w");

        wait();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Concatenas los argumentos que le llegan a "main" a la cadena que vas a ejecutar en el shell.